# How to merge rows with oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Im having trouble declaring an object from a row so it could be use in another column

This are the value inserted into a table TRIPLEG with format TripNum#, Length#, Origin, Destination

```
INSERT INTO TRIPLEG VALUES(10, 1, 'Perth', 'Sydney');
INSERT INTO TRIPLEG VALUES(10, 2, 'Sydney', 'Brisbane');
INSERT INTO TRIPLEG VALUES(11, 1, 'Sydney', 'Melbourne');
```

How do i actually merge them in a way so it will look like

```
T#   ORIGIN     DESTINATION1        DESTINATION2
---- ---------- ------------------- ----------------
10   Perth      Sydney              Brisbane
11   Sydney     Melbourne
```

I was asked to create a relational view, I was guessing it would look something like this:

```
Create view 
as select t#, origin, destination, destination
from TRIPLEG
```

But the Destination2 is the part where im not sure what to put.
Could anyone enlighten me on this?

Comment: have you considered normalisation?...

Comment: Sorry, but i haven't learn about normalisation. Are there other options? If not i'll have to look into it

Comment: It's not entirely clear from your question what you are trying to do...Are you after a self-join?

Comment: Im trying to get the 2nd destination from a same trip into a 4th column. As you can see in the same tripNum, the person travels from Perth->Sydney. Then next Sydney->Brisbane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many legs of the trip can there be? 3? 100? What you're looking for is a crosstab.

You haven't indicated what the columns in TRIPLEG are, so I'll assume t#, leg, origin, destination.

For the very specific case you have described, this will work:

```
SELECT 
"t#", 
MAX(DECODE(leg,1,origin)) origin, 
MAX(DECODE(leg,1,destination)) destination,
MAX(DECODE(leg,2,destination)) destination2
FROM TRIPLEG
GROUP BY "t#"
```

For just about any other case there are problems with it.

-If there are more than two legs

-If leg one finishes in Sydney but leg 2 doesn't start in Sydney

etc.

Try this, investigate crosstabs and ask more questions.

Comment: Hi electric, i tested ur code and yes this is exactly what im looking for! Now all i have to do is to put in the conditions.

Comment: Just be aware: this solution requires a lot of things to be correct in the source data to work. It's really the first stepping stone to the solution,  but it illustrates what can happen if the source data is unexpected. i.e. this won't show anything that has leg=3, leg=4 etc. To put it another way, your table design allows ambiguous data.

Comment: If this has helped, perhaps you could tick 'answer'